# iOs 8 show same app on same device differently than iOs7

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm having problems developing a game for two different screen sizes (the iPhone 4 and 5). This image is from the iPhone 4 simulator, this is how the game should look on every device:
[image]

iPhone 5 simulator with iOS 7:

[image]

But that one is from an iphone 5 too, but with ios 8:
[image]

Do I have to set up three different coordinates for each object, one for the iPhone 4 and 5 with iOS 7 and another one for iOS 8?

Will the iphone 6 and 6+ have different coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set positions relative to the screen size so that you do not have to specify coordinates for each.

Ex.  `Sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*5, self.frame.size.height*75)`

This will position your sprite center towards the top of the screen.  This way, objects will be placed in the same relative location for each screen size.

Your images will automatically scale.